PC boots to grub instead of windows boot manager after changing recovery partition
my pc was dual boot with windows 10 and ubuntu but later i uninstalled the ubuntu, I also believe I remove the partition containing the ubuntu boot loader manager
Recently, I needed to increase my recovery partition, so the KB5034441 update can be install
I follow this instruction, but instead of increasing the current recovery partition, i tried to "relocated" it, the reason for this is because the recovery partition is indexed at 0, and the primary is indexed at 4, so when I shrink the primary partition, the recovery partition wont able to extend its volume because the unallocated partition isn't adjacent to it. So I shrink the primary by 1gb, and create new recovery partition on that unallocated 1gb partition, making the new recovery partition at the bottom,

as you can see at the pic, the unallocated 530 mb is previously where the recovery partition was.
now the issue is everytime I turn on my pc, its boot to grub. I needed to enter "exit" so it can proceed to windows 10.

I want it to automatically boot to windows 10, I also tried to change the boot settings at bios, but I can't find the windows boot manager

I hadn't tried to repair the windows boot manager, since I finding many kinds of instructions relating to it, and also I really don't know what causing my problem, I mean I definitely know I stored the ubuntu boot manager or grub at separate partition when I install ubuntu, and I also know I remove the said partition when I uninstall the ubuntu, so why my pc boots to grub now.
I also want to note that I'm planning to upgrade my windows to 11, so that's why I tried to fix my KB5034441 update issue and also why my pc has this settings:

all disk are gpt
uses efi
secure boot enabled
tpm enabled

Again, I uninstall the Ubuntu long ago, and I didn't have this kind of problem, only this time after I make changes on recovery partition
Here's the result of bcdedit /enum
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {eaa8fdcc-9621-11ea-b226-fd586a991d36}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {6722a2ee-137a-11ef-b84e-2cf05d06595d}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {eaa8fdcc-9621-11ea-b226-fd586a991d36}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

This is what I did to verify the EFI partition, its looks like that the efi partition is at volume 1, while according to bcdedit /enum, it's at Volume3, based on this partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3. So is that the reason why my pc boots on grub instead of windows boot manager?

What should I do to make my pc automatically boots to windows 10?

Provide your boot configuration data entries (bcdedit /enum)

@Ramhound yes I can proceed to windows 10, if that's what you mean, but only when I enter exit at the grub command.

I suggest this solution.

@Ramhound I tried your suggestion to run this command bcdedit /enum

Verify the EFI partition is still actually \Device\HarddiskVolume3 since you deleted the first volume. Since you no longer have Linux on the drive you may as well purge the entry from EFI

@Ramhound I run, the command list vol, is this enough to verify the efi partition? kindly see the edited post

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Having fixed my own systems in order to install KB5034441 it does not appear your WINRE partition is even correct.  These instructions are correct. Volume3 appears to be a data archive partition, is that perhaps the volume, Linux was installed at one time? Did you go through this process to delete the Linux folder?

@Ramhound yes the data archive or volume 3 (disk 1) is where once the linux was installed, but the linux boot loader or grub was in the disk 0

@Ramhound Thank you it work, after I did this solution, sorry I didn't this as soon as possible, I'm just worried it might cause another problem, since I really didn't understand what cause my issue in the first place

Your boot configuration data is pointing to a partition which used to have Linux on it and as a result it goes into Grub. You should have left the unused WinRE partition, since it cannot easily be reclaimed, since you can’t merge it with any of the partitions
